# new instance of object acting as reference?

Tags: javascript, object, reference, prototype, instance

I am having a problem creating new instances of an object.

Using the below code I was expecting each element to have it's own random value (which is happening).

But then I was also expecting the `this.element` value to be contained to each instance of the  object, but instead every time the value is changed in any instance of the object it is updating in all of them.

```
var Instance = function(element) {
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.subInstance.parent = this;
}

Instance.prototype = {

    subInstance: {

        parent: null,
        $element: null,

        init: function() {
            var $this = this;
            this.$element = this.parent.$element;

            //test for what this.$element refers to in init function
            var random = Math.random();
            $('.element', this.$element).text('Updated ' + random);

            //test for what this.$element refers to in an event handler
            $('.element', this.$element).on('click', function(e) {
                $this.$element.css('background-color', '#f00');
            });
        }
    }
}
$('div.instance').each(function(i, o) {
    var instance = new Instance(o);
    instance.subInstance.init();
});​
```

Now I know I could move subInstance out of the prototype and into the constructor using `this.subInstance = {...` but that seems wrong, why is `this.$element` not contained to each instance of the object?

JSFiddle of both examples: http://jsfiddle.net/q7zAg/

Comment: Only Functions have a `this` value, not plain objects. The value of a Function have a `this` is set by the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may seem wrong, but it's not. If each object created from the constructor needs to work with a unique `subInstance`, you'll need to create a new one for each individual instance. On the `prototype` it will be shared.

*However*, one thing you could do would be to use `Object.create` to create a new instance that inherits from the prototyped `subInstance`. Then you get the benefit of some reuse, and each instance can modify its own object.

```
var Instance = function(element) {
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.subInstance = Object.create(this.subInstance);
    this.subInstance.parent = this;
}
```

Now some may argue that the `subInstance` still shouldn't be on the `prototype`, but rather should be a local variable in an IIFE. I would tend to agree with this.

Here's an example:

```
var Instance = (function() {
    var _subInstance = {
        parent: null,
        $element: null,
        init: function() {
            // ...
        }
    };

    var Instance = function(element) {
        this.$element = $(element);
        this.subInstance = Object.create(_subInstance);
        this.subInstance.parent = this;
    };

       // other prototyped props
    Instance.prototype.foo = "bar";

    return Instance;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that a function's `this` is set by how the function is called, not how it's declared or initialised (other than using *bind*).

In your code you have:

```
> Instance.prototype = {
>     subInstance: {
```

which assigns an object to `Instance.prototype` that has a `subInstance` property that is an Object.

Then there is:

```
>         init: function() {
>             var $this = this;
>             this.$element = this.parent.$element;
```

The method is called as:

```
> instance.subInstance.init();
```

So `this` within the `init` method always references the same object (i.e. `Instance.prototype.subInstance`), so assignments to `this.$element` keep replacing the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Obj = 
{
    internal:null,

    __init:function(data){
        this.internal = data;
        return this
    },
    get:function(){
        return this.internal;
    },
    init:function(){
        var args = arguments,instance = function(){
             return this.__init.apply(this,args);
        };
        instance.prototype = this;
        return new instance();
    }
}

console.log(Obj.init(123).get());
console.log(Obj.get());
console.log(Obj.init(321).get());
console.log(Obj.get());
```